# jQuery Array Difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is isn't really a question, it's a solution but I wanted to post it because I've seen it come up frequently. Feel free to suggest improvements though. I'll update my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/difster/qvbs6ps4/) with the results.

Using jQuery, this compares 2 arrays and outputs the differences in the two.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var foo = [];
var i = 0;
jQuery.grep(array2, function(el) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(el, array1) == -1) foo.push(el);
    i++;
});
alert(" the difference is " + foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Put the problem in the question, and the solution in an answer.

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: You could use `.map()` instead of `grep()`

Comment: When you use `grep`, the function should return a boolean that says whether to include the element in the result. Then you should assign the result to the array instead of using a global variable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for comments on working code is more suited for CodeReview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

The library Underscore.js is very helpful for stuff like this.

http://underscorejs.org/#difference

```
_.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);
=> [1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: why use another library when you can use native or jquery?

Comment: @MrNew Absolutely. This is just there in case you like this library, and want to start using it in your project :)